# Github Actions for Xcode

Tags: continuous-integration, xctest, xcodebuild, github-actions

I am trying to get Github Actions to work with my Xcode project but it won't.

Here's my file

```
name: CI

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - ci-test

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: [macos-latest]

    steps:
    - name: Force xcode
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.3.app
    - name: Start xcodebuild test
      # working-directory: 'My App'
      run: xcodebuild clean test -workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace' -scheme 'MyApp (Production)' -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,OS=13.3'
```

Further info:

- This is the final version of the file. In most of my attempts, it complained about not finding my .xcworkspace.
- This file resides in a specific feature branch, not on the master or a parent branch. I am not sure if this is relavent
- The xcodebuild command works fine locally
- Normally when I clone the repo on my Mac, the path is "where ever I choose/myapp-ios" and `myapp-ios` is the root directory where all my files including MyApp.xcworkspace are.
- When I tried doing "pwd" in the action, it printed a weird path (I am assuming it's due to the action running in a virtual machine) however the path ended as follows "weird path/myapp-ios/myapp-ios"
- I tried doing `cd ..` in the action file but that didn't work either
- I tried doing `git branch` in the action file but I got an error indicating that it's not a git repository (I am guessing it means that it is not initialized)
- I tried doing `ls` in the action file but it gave me bin/bash in the output instead of listing the files.
- At this point I am not sure if the branch is wrong or if the path is wrong but in a test project, things worked smoothly by just specify the working directory and the action file was pretty much the same. It's worth noting that in the test project, cloning the project put all the files in another folder in the root directory, unlike this project. That's why I have omitted the working directory command from the file.

Comment: Hi, do you have `- uses: actions/checkout@v2` as first job step to checkout your repository? https://github.com/actions/checkout

Comment: Yea that fixed it even if I put `- uses: actions/checkout@master`. I am still a bit confused how this line works especially that `master` and `v2` work interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still having trouble with this, but if so, I had to add the workspace prefix to get this to work correctly.

```
-workspace ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/MyApp.xcworkspace
```